# Draw points on an image visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, drawing

I have to insert an image to MFC dialog and print points on it when user checks a check box. Is it possible to draw points on an image in MFC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your own CStatic owner drawn based control for displaying your bitmap. When you get a DrawItem request load the original bitmap into a compatible DC. You can then draw on the DC your modifications and when finished BitBlt the DC to the actual screen DC provided in the DRAWITEMSTRUCT info.

Step by step.

1. Create a new MFC control based on CStatic called CMyPic
2. Put a Picture control on your dialog (as a place holder for your control)
3. Change the name of the picture control from IDC_STATIC to IDC_MYPIC
4. Change the Type of the control from 'Frame' to 'Owner Draw'
5. Right click on the control and 'Add variable'. Make it a control variable called something like m_mypic and change the variable type to CMyPic.
6. In CMyPic add an override for DrawItem
7. In DrawItem you can draw your bitmap (in my case I'm drawing a PNG and overlaying some text) something like this:

   ```
   void CMyPic::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct){

       CPngImage img;
       img.Load( IDB_PNG1 );

       CDC dcScreen;
       dcScreen.Attach( lpDrawItemStruct->hDC );

       CDC dcMem;
       dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC( &dcScreen );
       CBitmap * pold = (CBitmap*)dcMem.SelectObject( img );

       dcMem.DrawText( L"Hi", &lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem, NULL );

       dcScreen.BitBlt( 0, 0, lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.right, lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.bottom, &dcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

       dcMem.SelectObject( pold ); 
       dcScreen.Detach( );
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the answer @snowdude. I think this is little bit complex to me as I am new to MFC world.Anyway I will try it.

Comment: It sounds complex if you're new to MFC but it's not that hard. Take it in stages. 1. Create a MFC control based on CStatic. 2. Add that to your form. 3. Set it as Owner Drawn. 4. Override the DrawItem method. 5. Check your DrawItem is being called using the debugger. 6. Try drawing a bitmap in your DrawItem. If you get that far you've basically done it.

Comment: Updated the answer with a little more info on the step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @snowdude.That was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I'd *strongly* discourage doing it directly.

Generally, a dialog box should *only* act as a container for controls.

As such, what you probably want is some sort of layered drawing control that can display a bitmap as the background, and other objects (points, possibly lines, curves, etc.) in front of that. Writing an ActiveX control in MFC to do that borders on trivial. It's a *little* harder using ATL, but not much -- and the result will almost inevitably be "better" from the viewpoint of being smaller and (probably) faster.

Comment: Thanks Jerry Coffin. Could you please provide me some example? I am using CPropert page im MFC.

Comment: @gishu: I'm not sure what you're asking. It almost sounds like you're asking me to write a sample control for you, but I can't imagine that's what you're asking.

Comment: I m sorry, it was not what I asked. I am quite new to activex controls, so thats why asked you to suggest some examples where they have been used. Thanks.

Comment: @gishu: There are more samples writing ActiveX controls than of using them, simply because using them is generally pretty trivial. Nonetheless, at least as I recall the [`Circ` sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6hzbzz6.aspx) includes some code for a small program to host the control.